# Mockito return value only when method is called for second time

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In my simple example below, I am wondering how I can get `nameManager` to return a name only after `nameManager.getName()` is called for the second time with Mockito? (I know there are other things I can do, such as mocking what `saveName()` does)

I thought about using `doAnswer()`, but I don't know how to determine when `nameManager.getName()` has been called twice.

```
public void saveName(String name) {
  boolean doesNameExist = nameManager.getName(name).isPresent();
  if (!doesNameExist) {
    saveName(name);
    if (!nameManager.getName(name).isPresent()) {
      throw new Exception("Cannot verify name has been saved");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your unit test you can simply add the then clause twice. Like this -

```
@Test
public void yourUnitTest(){
    when(nameManager.getName(anyString())
        .thenReturn(null)
        .thenReturn(someValue);
    // your test
}
```

This will only return value when called second time and it will return null first time around.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I'm looking for :)